# How to bind to right mousebutton click in knockoutJs?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I just can't get knockout to bind to the right mousebutton click with the event binding. 
Mouseover etc. are working fine.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
   Andreas

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Ok...

Right after writing down my question I did find out how to solve it.

But I thought maybe other people run into the same question, so I'll post question and answer at the same time:

You can bind to the right mouseclick by binding to contextmenu :

```
<tr data-bind="event: { contextmenu: viewModel.ContextMenuClick }">
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I am attempting to do the same thing. I've got the click event bound to a function, but how did you then generate the context menu?

Comment: is there an extra closing curly in there?

Comment: don't forget to accept your answer now that the appropriate time has expired.  Especially since this is the first result on google for "knockout bind right click" :)

Comment: Note: `ContextMenuClick` is the function you'll create within your knockout vm, and will likely rename. For example in my case: `event: { contextmenu: handleRightClick }`